# Bind to Ancestor in Property sett

Tags: wpf, binding

I content control "MyControl" and this has a property "GlobalBackground".
For the items I have a style like this.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="XTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControlItem}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle Height="2" Fill="{Binding GlobalBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=local:MyControl}}"/>
            ...
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="XStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControlItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource XTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

This works as expected.

Now I want to use the same template bound to different properties of the Itemscontrol.
So the idea is to set a property via setter (Style Triggers)
When I do this

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="XTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControlItem}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle Height="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
            ...
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="XStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControlItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding GlobalBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=local:MyControl}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource XTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

the binding fails.

Is there no way to use FindAncestor bindings in a style setter or am I just doing something wrong?

Manfred

Comment: You can definitely do a `RelativeSource` `Binding` in a `Style`. If you debug your application, the output window in visual studio will show you your binding errors, which should help you get to the bottom of the error.

Comment: @abe
Yes I know - so I found the Problem (but no solution).
In the first case the binding works like a charm.
In the second case VS Shows "no ancestor of type.. found"
As I wrote in my answer to Sheridan I guess (not sure at all) that WPF tries (if used in a setter) to resolve the binding - while when I use it directly in template it resolves the binding at a time where the item is inside the items control, wich (of course) works

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have made an error declaring the `AncestorType`... see this example:

```
<Button Foreground="Blue" Background="Red">
    <Rectangle Margin="20" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="{Binding Foreground, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                    AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

Comment: As you may have noticed - in my first sample (the template) this binding works.
So the Ancestor finding works in General.
I guess, that WPF tries to assigne the value of the binding if used in a setter - and at this time the items control gets created and has no parent.